# Ruby Shoes GUI Secret style not working

Tags: ruby, user-interface, shoes

I am trying to make a login screen in Ruby Shoes. I am using the ask method to get the username and password but I want the password to show as asterisks. I have to use the secret method but I can't figure out the right syntax..

```
button "Login" do
    username = ask("Enter Username: ")
    password = ask("Enter Password: ") :secret => true
end
```

Should it be done this way?

```
password = ask("Enter Password: "), secret: true
```

I tried this too. It doesn't seem to work

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
  button "Login" do
    username = ask("Enter Username: ")
    password = ask("Enter Password: ", :secret => true)
  end
```